# PAYWALL CONTENT - JSON LD MARKUP in AMP-ACCESS

Tags: amp-html, amp-access

I have a question about AMP-ACCESS and ContentPaywall.

There is **no example** of how to do the JSON LD MARKUP in AMP for the contents with **AMP-ACCESS**, as if there is one for **AMP SUBSCRIPTION** where it indicates that you should include:

```
    "isPartOf": {
          "@type": ["CreativeWork", "Product"],
          "name": "The Norcal Tribune",
          **"productID": "norcal_tribune.com:basic"**
             }
```

Does **AMP-ACCESS** not need to include this in AMP microformats? Is no ProductID necessary?